# Checking to see if a given Date is within a work week (Monday-Friday)

Tags: javascript, date

How can I check and see if a given date, let’s call it (dateX) is within the (Present dates) work week (Monday-Friday)

Logic:

```
If (dateX is within the present work week of Monday-Friday) {  return true }
Else { return false }
```

Ie.

```
//Date Format is: yyyy-mm-dd
//dateX = 2016-10-11
If (2016-10-11 is within 2016-10-10 to 2016-10-14) { then return true }
Else { return false }
```

Comment: If you wan to see if a date is from Monday and Friday inclusive, then just check that *getDay* returns a value from 1 to 5 inclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

```
if(datebetweenCheck("10/09/2016","10/10/2016","12/09/2016"))
{
    alert("Yes");
}
else
{
    alert("No");
}

function datebetweenCheck(from,to,current) {

    var fromDate,toDate,currentDate;
    fromDate = Date.parse(from);
    toDate = Date.parse(to);
    currentDate = Date.parse(current);

    if((currentDate <= toDate && currentDate >= fromDate)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do not parse strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing). The format used is not consistent with any standard and parsing is implementation dependent.